# Protractor element is not attached to the page document

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, protractor

I am working with protractor for Angular6 Project, And I am having an issue with click element

**Scenario**
I am having a list of elements in a row (Table row), I want to click on each row.

**Issue**

I can click on the First element, But cannot click on the next one. Getting the below error message.

> element is not attached to the page document

**Code**
I am using each loop for looping elements And trying to click on each element

```
  $$('.categories2 ').each(function(Careers, index) { 
            Careers.all(by.tagName('button')).get(1).click();
            browser.driver.sleep(5000);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Each click causes page change. once page changed, selenium/protractor treat it as another page which is not the page in where `$$('.categories2 ')` executed.

When you get the next `Careers` from `$$('.categories2 ')`, it's not belong to the new page after click,but the page before click. That's why reports `not attached`.

To resolve your issue, you need to execute finding `$$('.categories2 ')` on each page after click.

```
$('.categories2 ').count().then((cnt)->{
    for(let i=0;i<cnt;i++) {
        $$('.categories2 ').get(i).all(by.tagName('button')).get(1).click();
        browser.driver.sleep(5000);
    }
})

// if you use async/await
let cnt = await $$('.categories2 ').count();
for(let i=0;i<cnt;i++) {
    await $$('.categories2 ').get(i).all(by.tagName('button')).get(1).click();
    await browser.driver.sleep(5000);
}
```